# Querying related records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two records in the oracle table that are related by a field called LEGAL_CLASS_PARENT_ID. How do i query to pull the records in one statement

[image]

```
select 
    id, FUND_ID, CLASS_TYPE, CURRENCY_ID, SUB_VOTING_ID,
    SUB_HOT_ISSUE_ID, REDS_FRQNCY_ID 
from 
    MGR.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS 
where 
    id = 13713

select 
    id, FUND_ID, CLASS_TYPE, CURRENCY_ID, SUB_VOTING_ID,
    SUB_HOT_ISSUE_ID, REDS_FRQNCY_ID, LEGAL_CLASS_PARENT_ID 
from 
    MGR.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS 
where 
    id = 28429
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join with connecting `LEGAL_CLASS_PARENT_ID` and `id`:

```
select id,FUND_ID,CLASS_TYPE,CURRENCY_ID,SUB_VOTING_ID,SUB_HOT_ISSUE_ID,REDS_FRQNCY_ID,LEGAL_CLASS_PARENT_ID 
from MGR.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS l2
join MGR.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS l 
on l.LEGAL_CLASS_PARENT_ID = l2.id
```

if you want specific id add `where`:

```
where id = 13713
```

Comment: I ran this query but it is pulling only one record that is the related record. I was to see both the parent and child record

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query to get all records connected by your parent child relationchip:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM MGR.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS
 START WITH ID = 28429
 CONNECT BY ID = PRIOR LEGAL_CLASS_PARENT_ID
```